# Different world opinions with my client, quit or stay?

Tags: difficult-client, ethics

For few months I have been working for one client and after that time I have realized something, that was not visible at first sight - my client is a person, who dislike people of other race and religion and is pro Russian, to put it lightly, who is xenophobic, racist, adores Putin, to put it bluntly.

The Russia / Putin I see like a different opinion or setting that everyone is entitled to, the other things I have a hard time accepting and I believe one should not.

What to do, however? I am building an intranet CRM system for whole company and my leaving would give a hard time also to other people. It also seems unprofessional to me. I am paid on a hourly basis and I have been already compensated for several months' work.

Sometimes I wonder what took me so long to realize it and I just feel that by staying I am actually helping to spread those ideas and once the system is finished, client will be more free and able to be even more proactive in advertising those ideas and supporting those political parties that do as well, for example.

So far I have stopped going for a lunch as I usually feel embarrassed there and when I tried to be an opponent, it seemed to have no effect. Or should I try harder?

Comment: Just to add, I am the only person developing the system on site and I am not fully dependent on this project.

Answer (score 4):

Are you working on-site or remotely? Seems like on-site work.

If you are working together with this guy, I can understand who you feel. Working environment for me is a thing which will push me work cheaper (for good team) or more expensive / leave (when team is bad).

Leaving for this reason is not silly at all. Things that bother you will influence your work in a year of a few years. I have myself quit my job for this very reason - atmosphere was bad and when I came home I was nervous and bad thoughts were constantly in my head.

If I were you, I would first try to move away from all things that bother you. It may work well for you. Each time when you have to talk to this guy, try to be on topic, and when he moves to off topic talk that you do not approve of, tell him that you have a lot of work to do and leave.

You are in this to earn something, so you have to try everything to see if you can work in such environment. If not, you will know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Business is business. If you don't do his work, others will. Make the most of it, and if it makes you feel unhappy, try to wrap it as soon as possible. Better yet, try to find another gig in the meantime, and when that's all set in, raise the price on the russian client. He'll either insist, or compensate fairly well, to shed your tears away.

Answer (score 2):

I promised myself years ago to never use my powers for evil :)

For me, first and foremost is my well being, that includes mental well being as well. I dislike supporting products/services I personally find offensive. They leave a sticky, gross, felling on me. This is different than work on a product service to support something I don't believe in.

I've worked on projects in the past which I *knew* preyed upon people's fears or ability to not see the "con" that was taking place - things like "this cures cancer" or "The economy is going to collapse". Clearly lies, but not offensive remarks. I always see these types of things as "buy beware" situations. Someone's going to do the work.. why not me. If there are "suckers" out there willing to buy into it, that's their fault. It's more a "free will" thing - the buyer/reader has a choice.

It's a thin line. Nonetheless I'm not adamant about only working on things I personally support. But I am adamant about not working on things which offend me or anyone I know.

So, first, I don't take on work for views which I consider unsavory. I'd never work for race-based organizations, regardless of the race. I'd never work in the porn industry, I'd never work for one particular political party today - I would have 30 years ago - etc. However, if I take on the work *then* find out other things which make the work unsavory I find an out. Either give considerable notice that I will be leaving or just outright quit.

Where this gets sticky is in a contract situation. If I've *legally* agreed to complete work, I must complete it. That is unless the other party breeches the agreement.

If I were to accept work, then find out the client is an overt racist I would **speak up**. Hiring me to complete work does *not* mean you hire control over my personal beliefs. When an offensive comment is made, I'd make it clear, *"Excuse me, that offends me. I'd appreciate it if you tried to curb your views [on other ethnic groups, religion, politics] when we speak."*

What's the worst that can happen? The client will either stop with the offensive remarks, or try and find a way out of working with me - win win for me.

Comment: Or possibly fire him/her.  Not that that's always a bad thing.

Comment: "find a way out of working with me" -- That includes termination. But if there's a contract... him/her breeching it is preferred, especially for these reasons.

Comment: Without going to too much details, the company provides rental of machines, I don't work on something that I would have personal problem with. The system will help people there and relieve them from the burden of manual administration. That's a good thing. 
As I am a solo developer, I have certain power, but don't want to misuse it. I can openly disagree and I am doing that, sometimes I take whole situation as a test..
Leaving is always an option, though it seems unfair to me, it would be good to have the job finished.

Comment: It really all comes down to your personal mental health. If it's merely an annoyance, then it may be worth it to just deal with it until the project is finished. If situations tend to ruin your overall outlook on life every day...then it may be worth it to leave.